# Hackproofing the site?

Tags: security

I don't know how to make my site hackproof at all. I have inputs where people can enter information that get published on the site. What should I filter and how?

Should I not allow script tags? (issue is, how will they put YouTube embed code on the site?)

iFrame? (People can put inappropriate sites in iFrames...)

Please let me know some ways I can prevent issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, run the user's input through a strict XML parser.
Reject any invalid markup.

You should use a whitelist of HTML tags and attributes (in the parsed XML).

Do not allow `<script>` tags, `<iframe>`s, or `style` attributes.

Run all URLs (`href` and `src` attributes) through a URI parser (eg, .Net's `Uri` class), and ensure that the protocol is `http`, `https`, or perhaps `mailto`.  Again, reject any invalid URLs.

If you want to allow YouTube embedding, add your own `<youtube>` tag that takes a URL or video ID as a parameter (content or attribute), and transform it into a script on the server (after validating the parameter).

---

After you finish, make sure that you're blocking everything on [this giant list](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html).

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as hacker proof. You want to do everything you can to decrease the possibility of being hacked. The most obvious weaknesses are going to be preventing against [xss (cross site scripting) hacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. There are easy ways to avoid both, most notably using newer technologies that instinctively seek to ward against them (text outputs that are encoded by default, conversions of queries before execution), etc.

If you need to go beyond those levels, there are a number of both automated (mostly fuzzy numbers you can give your sales guys after they are all "good") services that will "test" your system down to hard-core analysts that will pick apart your system for various audits.

Other than the basics mentioned above (xss & sql injection), the level of security you should try and obtain will really depend on your market.

Answer (score 3):

Didn't see this mentioned explicitly, but also use fuzzers ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing ).

It basically shoves random crap (strings of varying characters and length) into your input fields; It's used in industry practice bc it finds lots of bugs (ie. overflows).

http://www.fuzzing.org/ has a list of great fuzzers for you to try.

Answer (score 2):

You can check a penetration testing framework like [ISAAF](http://www.oissg.org/wiki/index.php?title=ISAAF-PENETRATION_TESTING_FRAMEWORK). It give you a check list and a methodology to test important security aspects of your application.